# What bit pattern represents the max value for double precision floating point?

Tags: javascript, binary, floating-point, ieee-754

I'm wondering how the max value is represented in 64 bits of double precision floating point. I assume it's represented with all 1's in exponent and mantissa like so:

```
0 11111111111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
```

If so, then why `Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308` shows the exponent of `308`, instead of `1024` decoded from `11111111111`? Is the bits pattern different?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're getting at, but `Number.MAX_VALUE.toString(2).length // 1024`

Comment: @squint, I'm sorry, what does it show?

Comment: MAX_VALUE binary representation utilizes 1024 bits, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: @squint, thanks, but that's confusing. Number can have only 64 bits, where do 1024 bits come from?

Comment: ...oh, that the max number represented in scientific notation can have 1024 binary places, at a loss of precision.

Comment: @squint, it's if we write out the bits represention in scientific form `1.1111...x2^1023` we will have `1024` bits. The question is what `toString` does with the number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

308 is decimal exponent while double uses powers of two.

Secondly max value exponent is reserved for infinity and NaN. Max-1 is the max exponent for regular number. Therefore the max number is written as:

```
01111111 11101111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

I.e. `0` sign bit, `2046` as exponent value (note that `1023` means actually zero exponent so `2046` means exponent of `1023`) and mantissa all ones (`1.11111(52 times)` in binary, the first one is hidden), in other words `1.11111(52 times)*2^1023`.

Converted to decimal it's `(2-(2^-52))*2^1023` which is about `1.79769313486231*10^308`.

For the double/float formats you can find very precise information on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Comment: _Max-1 is the max exponent for regular number_ - thanks, so the exponent should be 1023, not 1024 in binary then?

Comment: _2046 as exponent value_ - you have to subtract the bias of `1023`

Comment: @Maximus: this is an excellent answer - it is correct you know!

Comment: @Maximus : yes, value of `1023` is the middle (i.e. zero exponent). I updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000, yeah, I've learnt a lot already) Just got confused with this decimal exponent. Can you please also explain why `1.7976931x10^308, which is also 1x2^1024.` as Feathercrown stated?

Comment: `1.11111(51 times)` is the same as `10-0.000(50times)1` (note all are binaries so 10 is 2 in decimal), so the max is __almost__ `2^1024`, rounded up on 51st binary digit or 13th decimal digit. So Feathercrown is almost correct, it differs on 51st binary digit.

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000, why do you say _1.11111(**51** times)*2^1023_? It's actually **52** bits that go after the radix point, so 1.11111(**52** times)*2^1023 is what is represented in binary and I clearly understand that :). But the number in decimal is the problem

Comment: @Maximus : Sorry, my mistake. Yes, there are 52 bits in mantissa. So it differs at 52nd binary digit (after the radix point).

Comment: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000, can you please add to the answer how does this `1.11111(52 times)*2^1023` is translated to `1.7976931348623157e+308` in decimal?

Answer (score 2):

The exponent is 308 because that's 1.7976931x**10**^308, which is also 1x**2**^1024.

Answer (score 2):

The exponent is 308 since 308 is `1024 / (log 10 / log 2)`.

Remember that the 1024 is a binary exponent, but 308 is a denary exponent.